# Migration from Office 365 to postfix

Tags: postfix, microsoft-office-365

I'm facing a challenge: smoothly migrate users of a domain from 365 office Exchange to a multi-domain fully functional postfix server. The idea is that users can freely choose to either use their office webmail for the time being, or only use the new server.

I imagined doing some "deliver locally + relay" combo on the postfix side, then switch the MXes towards it, but I'm not sure it's the way to go and I don't see either how to configure postfix to do so, not even knowing if M$ will still correctly route the mails after the MX switch.

I was wondering if someone had some experience to share on the subject.

On the office 365, I can apparently create a "connector" to white-list my server certificate. On the postfix side, I thought of a bcc regexp map to deliver locally and then relay, but to which domain? The bcc trick doesn't seem helpful here.

Is there a way to tell postfix to relay to a relayhost IP (rather than a domain) *after* local delivery?

Having Office 365 be the primary email server is not an option, as new users won't have an Office 365 account.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: One of the things you will want to read up on is postfix `transport`.  You can relay mail to any domain name or IP based on incoming domain.  You can even override the port if you wish.  Remember to `postmap transport` and to test this with a test domain.

Comment: Thanks. My thoughts so far: keep foo.com transport to :virtual, but bcc to user@relay.foo.com, then use an :smtp transport for relay.foo.com with an extra smtp_generic_maps to rewrite the addresses towards user@foo.com when they leave my server. I'll share my results.

Comment: Why do not leave the existing users on office365 and create the new users on postfix?

Comment: Because after a while we'll be leaving office365.